# Too many setTimeout in IE

Tags: javascript

I use comet to update my page content, and show the update effect by adding a class and using setTimeout to clear the class. If there are a lot of updates coming, there will be a lot of timers on the page. In firefox, this is still working fine, but in IE, the color is not cleared within the timeout i specified. Is there any problem if there are too many timeouts for IE?

Comment: @Pointy: but only six questions.

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure your requests are not being cached? No example code means crappy answers.